# String.to_atom hardcodes the underlying erlang.binary_to_atom encoding option to :utf8, why?

Tags: erlang, elixir

Why does String.to_atom hardcode the encoding option to :utf8 ?

https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/d6bb3342b7ea8b921b3d4b69f65064c4158c99d7/lib/elixir/lib/string.ex#L1927

 `def to_atom(string) do
    :erlang.binary_to_atom(string, :utf8)
  end`

The available encoding options for erlang `binary_to_atom` are :

`latin1 | unicode | utf8`

http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-8.0-rc1/erts-8.0/doc/html/erlang.html#binary_to_atom-2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Because the Erlang universe is finally settling on UTF-8 everywhere.

**Discussion**

`latin1` is going away and is largely a subset of UTF-8 (except a few characters), `unicode` is an old alias for `utf8`, and that leaves us with just one universally applicable option: `utf8`. This is important since UTF-8 atoms (and strings) are the way forward within Erlang and also within Elixir.

If you are dealing in old data with non-UTF-8 encodings then convert it *before* your call to `binary_to_atom/2`.

This also falls in line with the newer `string` and `unicode` module changes in Erlang's standard library -- which can *finally* settle on UTF-8 as a generally accepted standard after decades of uncertainty (because *encodings are hard* and there was not much agreement about this when Erlang was invented).

**A word on coding practice**

I work in Japan handling mostly business data, some of it quite old, and some of it in really crazy encodings. I tend to code mostly in Erlang (I prefer tiny languages). When some of the older string handling functions and unicode module were written strings fell into two categories:

- **A list of code points in ASCII** (that was implicitly extend to encompass latin1 quite a bit of the time because, well, European languages were a common use and CJK was a wild mess back then)
- **Some waking nightmare of dragonfire and frost zombies** (because there was zero agreement about anything else and a gazillion radically incomplete, half-baked, technically inaccurate "standards")

Times have changed. Now we know that strings are nearly always going to be in UTF-8 and everything in the Unixverse has finally settled on this which has had the pleasant effect of having (pretty much) every other meaningful system settle on that as well (if not internally, then through robust detection libraries that can pick between UTF-16 and UTF-8).

The cases where you actually *do* have non-UTF-8 data *then you know this to be the case* and should convert your data before sending it to a universal function such as `binary_to_atom/2`. I actually think we should shift next to including a `binary_to_atom/1` and phase out `binary_to_atom/2` entirely -- [which is what has already happened with `list_to_atom/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_atom-1) as of Erlang R20 (yay!).

So how does that affect your code?

When you start dealing in ancient encodings the complexity of your code *suddenly explodes* and that needs to be contained right away lest it infect your entire codebase with insanity. The best way to do this is to keep the crazy outside of your business system proper and do conversions out at the edges. Whenever we deal in old data that comes in crazy encodings *we already know* and are prepared for that -- so we convert to UTF-8 explicitly right up front, so there isn't anything left to encounter later on deeper in the system.

You might think, "Why don't they just detect the encoding of every string?" Alas, *there is no proper way to detect string encodings*. It is just not possible with a high degree of confidence. It is also quickly becoming an obsolete task in the majority case as the vast majority of data generated today is UTF-8 (or UTF-16, but it is very rare to encounter this over the wire).